# "Bus Distance" in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, geospatial

In a specific city, is there a way to find out the amount of kilometers needed to travel between two points (e.g. 2 pairs of lat/long) by bus?

I found the following post that shows how to find out walking and driving distance:

```
#install

remotes::install_github("riatelab/osrm")

# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/osrm/versions/3.5.1/topics/osrmRoute 

route1 <-  osrmRoute(src = c(13.412, 52.502),
                     dst = c(13.454, 52.592), osrm.profile = "foot")

route2 <-  osrmRoute(src = c(13.412, 52.502),
                     dst = c(13.454, 52.592), osrm.profile = "car")

route3 <-  osrmRoute(src = c(13.412, 52.502),
                     dst = c(13.454, 52.592), osrm.profile = "bike")

#
route1$distance
```

But it does not seem like there is a "bus option" here. Is this possible in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `osrm` package because [project OSRM](http://project-osrm.org) does not support bus directions. However the `googleway` package offers access to the Google Maps API. You can use this to calculate distance using the Distance Matrix API. You cannot specify bus specifically, but can calculate distance using transit, which includes bus and other modes of public transit.

```r
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

google_distance(
  origin = c(52.502, 13.412),
  destination = c(52.592, 13.454),
  mode = "transit",
  key = key
)
#> $destination_addresses
#> [1] "Alt-Blankenburg 26, 13129 Berlin, Germany"
#> 
#> $origin_addresses
#> [1] "Prinzessinnenstraße 20, 10969 Berlin, Germany"
#> 
#> $rows
#>                            elements
#> 1 13.3 km, 13286, 42 mins, 2507, OK
#> 
#> $status
#> [1] "OK"
```

Comment: Wow this is really cool! Too bad there is no free option :(